# Case-insensitive regexp quick check

Tags: javascript, regex

```
"kuku".match(/KUKU\/i/)
```

What should I tweak here, so that `true` (or matching array) will be returned?

Comment: why did you include the backslash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about

```
"kuku".match(/KUKU/i)
```

Comment: yohooo! it works (will accept the answer as soon as the system allows). can you please enlist a reference URL as a supplementary?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html - although I probably should encourage you to search the web for 'javascript regular expression case insensitive' ;)